# How to create blurred and colored shadows in React Native Android under view

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, shadow, dropshadow

For ages I was trying to create beautiful, modern components in React Native on Android, however it's seems to be not that easy. What I want to create is something like in here:

[image: view shadow]

However, still the only thing that works on android is `elevation`, with which I cannot make such great effect of drop shadow under the component.

I was trying several libraries to achieve this effect, but no luck. E.g:

- react-native-shadow-2
- react-native-drop-shadow
- @vesselsoft/react-native-shadow
  and a few more, and they don't work (on Expo), or don't give such effect.

Is it somehow possible to create such blurred, colored drop shadow under view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, and the effect is really close to what I posted. I can't change shadow offset and distance, but at least from Android API 28 `shadowColor` property works, and you can set shadow color different than black.